# Phonegap App for Android: display Admob Ads in a div

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova, mobile

I am trying to implement Ads via Admob in my mobile App for Android using Phonegap. I've written the whole Code using HTML+Javascrip/Jquery and now I am building a native App with Phonegap.

I can see ads via Admob using this code:

```
public class ModernSnake extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final String AdMob_Ad_Unit = "a151376a873f810";
    private AdView adView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 10000);
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdMob_Ad_Unit); 
        LinearLayout layout = super.root;
        layout.addView(adView); 
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.setTesting(true);
    adView.loadAd(request);

}
```

}
But the problem is that the banner is at the bottom of the page the whole time.

So is it possible to call the adView function via Javascript and maybe display it in a div I've created before?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using a JavascriptInterface and call a function in Java that hides/shows the layout of the ads.